# Switching between Tabs with NgIf

Tags: javascript, angular

I have to build a component with two tabs and switch between tabs with a simple **ngif**.  
I first did this:

```
...
export class ButtonComponent {
 firstTab = true;
 secondTab = false;

onFirstTab() {
    this.firstTab = false;
    this.secondTab = true;
}

onSecondTab() {
    this.firstTab = true;
    this.secondTab = false;
}
```

And in HTML

```
<ion-segment value="active">
  <ion-segment-button value="active" (click)="onFirstTab()">
    <ion-label>Component</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
  <ion-segment-button (click)="onSecondTab()">
    <ion-label>Attribute & Code</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div *ngIf=“firstTab” class="animated">
Content 1
</div>
<div *ngIf=“secondTab” class="animated">
Content
</div>
```

It worked perfect, but my worry is that I found it a repetitive code. I have tried a way to use JUST ONE variable to toggle between tabs. Since there will be just two tabs.

The question is:
Is there a way to build a simpler/cleaner toggle in Angular to switch between Tabs with ONE variable (ON/OFF)?

Comment: The question title is ambiguous and it is a really basic question about how to use "if else" in Angular's View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a tabIndex would work

```
export class ButtonComponent {
 tabIndex = 0;


setActiveTab(index: number) {
    this.tabIndex = index;
}

<ion-segment value="active">
  <ion-segment-button
   *ngFor="let tabTitle of ['Component', 'Attribute & Code']; let i = index"
    [attr.value]="i === tabIndex  ? 'active' : ''"
    (click)="setActiveTab(i)"
  >
    <ion-label>{{ tabTitle }}</ion-label>
  </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

 <div *ngIf=“tabIndex == 0” class="animated">
  Content 1
 </div>
 <div *ngIf=“tabIndex == 1” class="animated">
  Content
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is much simple than mine approach and works!

Comment: Thanks for accepting as aswer. Think it's even better to add a ngFor: *ngFor="let tabTitle of ['Component', 'Attribute & Code']; let i = index" should I update my answer with that?

Comment: yes please update the answer if you think there is a better solution. But rather added it as a second version

Comment: I updated my answer, next stept will be could be with routerLinks instead of showing content using ngIf

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this with just one property called `activeTab` and one method `setActiveTab()` to set the active tab value:

```
export class ButtonComponent {
  activeTab = 0;

setActiveTab(tabIndex: number) {
  this.activeTab = tabIndex;
}
```

In the template:

```
<ion-segment value="active">
   <ion-segment-button value="active" (click)="setActiveTab(1)">
     <ion-label>Component</ion-label>
   </ion-segment-button>
   <ion-segment-button (click)="setActiveTab(2)">
     <ion-label>Attribute & Code</ion-label>
   </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>

<div *ngIf=“activeTab === 0” class="animated">Content 1</div>
<div *ngIf=“activeTab === 1” class="animated">Content</div>
```

This way, as you keep adding tabs, you don't need to modify your class, duplicating the methods.